# Item-level security possible with OData external content type?

Tags: 2013, bcs, enterprise-search, odata

I've created an External Content Type which uses an OData service as it source, and I created a content source in the Search Service Application in order to crawl this data.
This works fine.

However, I need security-trimmed search results.
I found this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg294169.aspx
which describes how to implement item level security, but it seems to apply to ECT's which are backed by WCF services or direct database access only.

I can imagine that I could include the ACL info in a field in my OData results, but how to configure the ECT to make use of that provided information ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that does not work for wcf/odata sources because there is no "standardized" format for the ACL - in code you can translate the incoming ACL to an acl the index understands - but as you mentioned, you need BCS/Custom Connector for this.